Get ssl client certificate from socket object after failing to verify the certificate
I have a socket server written in python accepting connections like:
self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# set the socket as non-blocking
self.socket.setblocking(False)

# bind
self.socket.bind((self.host, int(self.port)))

# listen
self.socket.listen()

In a separate async function, I'm calling:
conn, address = await self.loop.sock_accept(self.socket)

Once the connections is made, it is passed to :
loop.connect_accepted_socket(lambda: <custom asyncio.Protocol class>, ssl=ssl_context)

When the connection fails to establish, the error is caught under:
except ssl.SSLError as e:
   print(e)

Where e can be a range of ssl errors.
Some of them are:

[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER]
[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_CERTIFICATE] sslv3 alert bad certificate (_ssl.c:1091)

Under such scenarios, I'd like to be able to print out the certificate that we had received from the client.
Is there a way to do this?
I've tried printing conn.getpeercert() in the exception handler, however I get the error message:

AttributeError: 'socket' object has no attribute 'getpeercert'

Whereas, if the connection does succeed, I'm able to get the peer certs from the transport object by calling:
transport.get_extra_info("peercert")

I'd like to know if there is a way to print the certificate received from the client upon failure to verify.

With WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER there will be no certificate send by the server. With SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_CERTIFICATE the certificate is already gone since the socket is closed, so you would need to catch it before the socket gets closed.
When looking at the underlying OpenSSL the usual way to catch the certificate in this case is to implement a SSL verify callback  on the SSL context. But this functionality is not exposed in Python, so you are probably out of luck.

Would it be possible for me to write my own verification function for the certs in python. Then pass ssl_verify=False in the ssl context to be able to read the certs at all times?

@AnirudhPanchangam:  Would it be theoretically possible: yes. But it is not trivial, so better use existing code like https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/verification/ . And you need to make sure that you do the verification before any application data gets transferred.

Thanks, i'll accept this as the answer.
